# Play separate sound for each inbox in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

At work, I monitor two mailboxes in Outlook. The first is the mailbox assigned individually to me: me@company.com. The other one is shared between a number of people on my team: group@company.com.

When new mail arrives for me@company.com, Outlook plays a sound and posts a notification, as expected. However, when mail arrives for group@company.com, Outlook doesn't notify me. The problem is that when a message arrives for group@company.com, by nature it requires urgent attention.

How can I make Outlook play a sound of my choosing when new mail arrives to group@company.com?

What I've tried already:

1. I've looked through the Outlook settings and can't find anything relevant.
2. I've created a rule to play a sound for all new messages to group@company.com, but it never gets triggered. It seems that rules can only see mail going to me@company.com.
3. I saw an old article from 2013 about using PowerShell to control Outlook. However, I couldn't seem to get it to work, possibly because either, a) things have changed since 2013, or b) I did something wrong, not having prior PowerShell scripting experience and all.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there's no such an option to set it for shared mailbox in Outlook desktop client. As a workaround, it's suggested that you could add you shared mailbox in OWA, and then you will get the notification of new emails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It didn't seem to solve my problem, unfortunately.